# Access all @RequestHeader key value as Map in our Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to find way through which, I can populate all Key values from @RequestHeader annotation to a Map.
I tried to Google it but all I can find is a way to map each key value to one parameter.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm")
    public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="User-Agent") String userAgent)

        //..
    }
}
```

But I want to achieve something like this.

@RequestHeader Map headerParam;

So that I can traverse the Map and use all header values as required.

Comment: Have you actually tried it with a map... (and have read the original [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for pointing out, I missed that somehow, Documentation seems clear.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can achieve it as follow-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm")
public String hello(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders){
    Map<String,String> headerMap=httpHeaders.toSingleValueMap();
    //TODO httpHeaders will have many methods
}
```

I hope it will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what kind of map does Spring create? a hash or TreeMap?

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring boot below mapping would work

@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers

```
@PostMapping(value = "/customer", produces = { "application/json" })
ResponseEntity<String> findName(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
```

}

Comment: Do you know what kind of map does Spring create? a hash or TreeMap?